# UICollectionView selecting a previously selected cell after reuse

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a custom `UICollectionViewCell`, it can select and deselect single cells. The problem comes when you select then deselect the cell, scroll thru the `UICollectionView` and when you go back the previously selected cell shows that it's being selected. This is some reusability issue.

This is how I'm selecting and deselecting the cell:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)! as! CreateNotebookCVCell
    if selectedIndexPath != indexPath || selectedIndexPath == nil {
        // Select Cell
        selectedIndexPath = indexPath
        cell.showDimViewAndCheckmark()
        selectedCover = notebookCovers[indexPath.row]
        saveButton.isEnabled = true
    }
    else {
        // Deselect Cell
        selectedIndexPath = nil
        cell.hideDimViewAndCheckmark()
        selectedCover = nil
        saveButton.isEnabled = false
    }
}
```

And this is the code in the cell itself:

override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        setUI()
     //   hideDimViewAndCheckmark()
    }

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    hideDimViewAndCheckmark()
    coverImageView.image = nil
}

func hideDimViewAndCheckmark() {
    dimView.isHidden = true
    checkmarkIcon.isHidden = true
}

func showDimViewAndCheckmark() {
    dimView.isHidden = false
    checkmarkIcon.isHidden = false
    dimView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    dimView.clipsToBounds = true
    dimView.layer.borderWidth = 2
    dimView.layer.borderColor = Colors.purpleDarker.cgColor
    dimView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMaxXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
}

override var isSelected: Bool {
    didSet {
        if isSelected {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: { [unowned self] in
                self.showDimViewAndCheckmark()
            })
        }
        else {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: { [unowned self] in
                self.hideDimViewAndCheckmark()
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here

UPDATE: `cellForRowAt` method as requested

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: Cell_Id.createNotebook, for: indexPath) as! CreateNotebookCVCell
    let cover = notebookCovers[indexPath.row]
    cell.coverImageView.image = UIImage(named: cover)
    return cell
}
```

Comment: post your cellForItemAt method code

Comment: @Shruti I've added it

Comment: but why are you calling `showDimViewAndCheckmark` two times? One in didSelect and one when var isSelected is set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

--cellForItem function

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CreateNotebookCVCell

    if selectedIndexPath == indexPath{
        cell.showDimViewAndCheckmark()
        selectedCover = notebookCovers[indexPath.row]
        saveButton.isEnabled = true
    } else {
        cell.hideDimViewAndCheckmark()
        selectedCover = nil
        saveButton.isEnabled = false
    }

    return cell
}
```

-- didSelectItemAt function

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


if selectedIndexPath != indexPath || selectedIndexPath == nil {
    // Select Cell
    selectedIndexPath = indexPath
} else {
    // Deselect Cell
    selectedIndexPath = nil
}

collectionView.reloadData()
}
```